# How can I display specific properties from Active Directory's Attribute Editor, such as 'serialNumber' as string?

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory

I'm running a PowerShell command and filtering for serialNumber. When I run in PowerShell, I get correct output. When I run in Windows Forms app, I get:

```
@{serialNumber=Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection}
```

Any ideas on how to convert this string into the actual serialNumber?

```cs
PowerShell psinstance = PowerShell.Create();
psinstance.AddScript("Get-ADUser " + user.SamAccountName + " -Properties serialNumber | select serialNumber");
var results = psinstance.Invoke();
foreach (var outputItem in results)
{
     Debug.WriteLine(outputItem.ToString() + "\n");
}
```

Comment: `select serialNumber` -> `select -Expand serialNumber`

Comment: `select -expand serialNumber`

Comment: @Matt Heh. I win. ;)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers *shakes fist* I'll get you next time.

Comment: You guys are awesome. Thank you :) Create an answer and I'll accept it.